# Java Stream API's Collectors.toList() and Collectors.toSet() mechanics

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

If I have HashSet and I use stream  .filter() for some operations and then do `.collect(Collectors.toList())` would that be inefficient compared to just collecting the stream back to a HashSet `.collect(Collectors.toSet())`?

Would that take a similar time as explicitly converting a HashSet to a List `O(n)` or is Stream a different state from where it would take about similar time to add elements back to a List or to a Set?

The dataset is significantly large. I would like to go with a List because it consumes less memory but I don't want to sacrifice speed for that.

**Code Sample Example:**

```
Set<Object> originalSet;  // this is a set containing 800,000 Objects

// Scenario 1
List<Object> newList = originalSet.stream().filter(Object::isEnabled).collect(Collectors.toList())
   
// Scenario 2 
Set<Object> newSet = originalSet.stream().filter(Object::isEnabled).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: Can you show a code example rather than describing the code in words? "A picture's worth a 1000 words"

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: @Sweeper I am not that familiar with stream API and so am trying to understand if stream changes data to a different state which then converts back to the original DataStructure when using .collect() method or is it just iterating and filtering and removing elements. I have looked online but didn't find a clear answer so just asking for some help to clear things out.

Comment: @StackOverthrow It is conceptually no different from a for-loop containing an if-statement which adds to a new list or set. It's that, but in a functional style.

Comment: Both `toList` and `toSet` creates new collection objects to store the results. One of them is not going to suddenly get faster if you streamed from a `List` instead. Does that answer your question?

Comment: It doesn't change data in the initial collection at all.  Streams don't keep any aspect of "this came from a HashSet."

Comment: Yes, that does answer my question. I appreciate the explanations @Michael, Sweeper, and Louis Wassweman

Comment: @LouisWasserman You're basically right, but "*any aspect*" is an overstatement. A stream does retain *some* flags based on the source, which can have subtle influences on the behaviour. A stream from a list will have the ORDERED flag, and a stream from a set should have the DISTINCT flag: https://ideone.com/QXTIpC

Answer (score 2):

Collecting to a List is faster than collecting to a Set. This is because when collecting to a set, for each value, it needs to find its hashcode and based on this hashcode know where in memory to put this value.

So the question is should we always collect to List instead of Set? No, it depends on the situation. If later in the code you need to check if an element exists in this list or set, it is much faster to search the set. The complexity to search within the list is o(n) while using .contains on the set is just o(1).
So to conclude, use the Set if you have code that uses .contains, but use List if you just need to iterate it later.

Comment: It’s “Big O” not “little o”. But basically, you’re right. The main concern should be “*What do I need afterwards?*” If it is “just a collection”, collecting to a `List` tends to be faster, especially when you use the newer `toList()` operation directly on the `Stream`, rather than `collect(…)`.

Comment: I understand the pros and cons of both Lists and Sets, I wanted to go with List, but I was just worried that I would spend extra time converting from the Set to a List. So basically my question in this post was "Would that take a similar time as explicitly converting a HashSet to a List O(n) or is Stream a different state from where it would take about similar time to add elements back to a List or to a Set?", I did get some insights on that in the question's comments.

Comment: You’re not converting. You’re iterating over the elements with a filter and adding the accepted elements into a new collection. A Stream might have internal optimizations for certain scenarios, but none applies here. Note that even when your starting point is `HashSet<Object> originalSet;` and you’re doing a plain copy like `HashSet<Object> copy = new HashSet<>(originalSet);` (or `originalSet.clone()`), no such optimization will happen in OpenJDK, on which most environments are built. In other words, even then, `new ArrayList<>(originalSet)` will be faster.

Comment: @Holger That makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!